# Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to create and delete blobs with the following code. Why am I getting this error? **CreateIfNotExists - Method Not Found**.  I get the same when I try and **ListBlobs**.

What am I missing?  What is the correct version of **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage**

Here's my code

```
 var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(BlobConnString);

            var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = myClient.GetContainerReference(Mycontainer);

            container.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);

            foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
            {
                if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
                    if (directory.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains(NIPRprocfolder))
                    {
                        IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);
                        ICloudBlob bi;
                        foreach (var blob in blobs)
                        {
                            if (blob is CloudBlockBlob)
                            {
                                bi = blob as CloudBlockBlob;
                                if (bi.Name.Contains(".xml"))
                                {
                                    _logger.Info($"Deleting report : {bi.Name} from {NIPRprocfolder}");
                                    bi.DeleteIfExists();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

thx

Comment: What's the SDK version/target .Net framework you're using?

Comment: Support for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists`was removed in version **7.2.0**. The current storage extension uses version 9.3.3 of the storage SDK. You could use the `CreateIfNotExistsAsync` method present in the newer SDK. You can use `.Wait()` with the Task returned by this method to effectively make it synchronous.